# Why is Chrome not Blocking Third-Party Cookies on YouTube Visit?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Here's my Chrome configuration. You can see it's configured to block third-party cookies and for the most part it does just that.

There's one weird exception, however. When I visit the site `MMAJunkie.com` and then immediately visit `YouTube.com`, cookies from the former site are apparently read/written when visiting the latter one. Here are two images showing Allowed Cookies and Blocked Cookies when landing on the YouTube site. Although it only happens occasionally, you can see that the `MMAJunkie` third-party cookie isn't being blocked as it should be.

[image: Google Chrome cookie settings]